# React Native Elements ChekBox onPress not changing status

Tags: javascript, react-native

Does the onPress in react native elements checkbox work? When I click on the checkbox, nothing changes.

```
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements'

...
render() {
   const { myValue } = this.state;
   console.log(myValue);

   return (
      ...

      <CheckBox
         title="My Test?"
         iconRight
         checked={myValue}
         onPress={() => this.setState({myValue: !this.state.myValue})}
     />
   );
}
```

I click on the CheckBox and it never changes to checked. The log always shows `false`

Comment: since you already desctructured `myValue` from state. You should just have ```this.setState({ myValue })```

Comment: It won't change anything. Same issue

Comment: can you share your initial state values

Comment: The initial value is false.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that there is no 'onPress' method for the CheckBox element you have. For example, Material-UI's CheckBox element has an 'onChange' function which takes a callback function in (just like the one you have in your code).

Here is the link for Material-UI's CheckBox API https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/#props

Try out the following code:

```
<CheckBox
    title="My Test?"
    iconRight
    checked={myValue}
    onChange={() => this.setState({myValue: !this.state.myValue})} // instead of 'onPress'
/>
```

Comment: Still the same issue with onChange. https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/1.1.0/checkbox.html